# Prove that there is a continuous function $f:(0,a)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ ($a>0$) such that $f\notin\mathcal{L}_q(\lambda)$ for all $q\in (0,+\infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Prove that there is a continuous function $f:(0,a)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ ($a>0$) such that $f\notin\mathcal{L}_q(\lambda)$ for all $q\in (0,+\infty)$.

I think $f(x)=e^{1/x}$ works but I don't know how to prove it. I have to demonstrate that $\int |f|^q\,d\lambda=+\infty$ but I don't know how to do it. My only idea is to define the sequence of functions $(f_n)$:

$$
f_n(x)=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  e^{n/a}&\mbox{if }x<a/n\\
  e^{1/x}&\mbox{if }x\geq a/n
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

So we have that $\lim_{n\uparrow+\infty}f_n=f=|f|$ and that $\lim_{n\uparrow+\infty}f_n^q=|f|^q$.

Thus,
$$\int |f|^q\,d\lambda\geq\int f_n^q\,d\lambda\geq\int_{(0,a/n)}f_n^q\,d\lambda=(a/n)e^{qn/a}=q\frac{e^{qn/a}}{qn/a}\xrightarrow{n \to+\infty}+\infty$$

This is what I have but I am not really sure that my demonstration is correct. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {e^{qy}} y \to \infty$ as $ y \to \infty$ (for any $q >0$). Hence there exist $M$ such that $\frac {e^{qy}} y >2$ if $y >M$. Taking $x=\frac  1y $ see that This gives $e^{q/x} >\frac 2 x$ for $0< x<\frac  1M$. Now it is easy to show that $\int_0^{a} e^{q/x} dx=\infty$.

Comment: I don't understand why there exist $M$ such that $\frac{e^{qy}}{y}>2$ if $x > M$. What is the relationship between $x>M$ and $\frac{e^{qy}}{y}>2$?

Comment: You mean $\exists M:y>M\Rightarrow\frac{e^{qy}}{y}>2$?

Comment: @KKLK Corrected.

Comment: Thank you very much, the only thing that is not so clear to me is why if $\int_0^ae^{q/x}\,dx=+\infty$ then the Lebesgue integral is also infinite. I know that the lebesgue integral and the riemann integral coincide when the function is bounded but I have read that in the case of improper integrals this is not always true.

Comment: Lebesgue integral form $\epsilon$ to $a$ equals the Riemann integral from $\epsilon$ to $a$. In both cases the integral from $0$ to $a$ is the limit oft the corresponding integral as $ \epsilon \to 0$. @KKLK

Answer (score 1):

Exercise: For any $q>0,$ $\dfrac{e^{nq}}{n}\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty.$

So let $q>0.$ Then for any $n\in \mathbb N,$

$$\int_0^1 (e^{1/t})^q\,dt =\int_0^1 e^{q/t}\,dt $$ $$\ge\int_0^{1/n} e^{q/t}\,dt > e^{nq}/n.$$

By the exercise, $\int_0^1 (e^{1/t})^q\,dt= \infty.$

Comment: Thank you. My only question is why if the Riemann integral is infinite then the Lebesgue integral is also infinite. I understand that in the case of improper integrals both integrals do not always coincide.

Comment: Riemann integrals are never infinite. They either exist or don't, but if they do, they are finite. Furthermore, when they exist, so does the Lebesgue integral, and the two are equal.